# angular-meteor find MongoDb collection and return based on params

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to get warnings for a certain address in my MongoDb, using a combination of Meteor and Angular.js

In my html file, I'm doing

```
<div ng-controller = "myController as myCtrl">
{{myCtrl.warnings}}
{{myCtrl.getWarnings("123 Test Street, TestCity, TestState")}}
</div>
```

in my app.js file:

```
Warnings = new Mongo.Collection("Warnings");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var app = angular.module('ffprototype', [ 'angular-meteor' ]);

  app.controller('myController', ['$window','$meteor', function($window, $meteor) {

    this.warnings = $meteor.collection(Warnings);

    this.getWarnings = function(findByAddress){
        Warnings.find({address: findByAddress}).fetch();
    }
  }]);
}
```

my mongoDb collection:

```
{
    "_id": "3ixgxEMZDWGtugxA7",
    "address": "123 Test Street, TestCity, TestState",
    "warning": "Warning 1"
}
{
   "_id": "HZH5FvCD5driBYSJz",
    "address": "123 Test Street, TestCity, TestState",
    "warning": "Warning 2"
}
```

The output from the html webpage shows the entire Warnings collection (thanks to `{{currentDispatch.warnings}}`, but nothing gets displayed for `{{currentDispatch.getWarnings("123 Test Street, TestCity, TestState")}}`

Answer (score 6):

You should use [$meteor.object](http://angularjs.meteor.com/api/meteorObject) for this

```
this.getWarnings = function(findByAddress){
  $meteor.object(Warnings, { address: findByAddress }, false); // passing false here to not update the collection from changes in the client
}
```

Comment: If I do this, won't I loose the auto-publish features?  the `this.warnings = $meteor.collection(Warnings);` pushes updates to the database automatically, but when I have to "return" something isn't that lost?

Comment: thanks I'll try this out when I get home and if this works I'll accept and you'll get your points

Comment: according to the documentation: `A service that wraps a Meteor object to enable reactivity within AngularJS. Finds the first document that matches the selector, as ordered by sort and skip options. Wraps collection.findOne`  I need ALL matches not just "findOne" functionality.

Comment: @Matt Westlake If you need all matches then do the same but with $meteor.collection:  this.getWarnings = function(findByAddress){
  $meteor.collection(Warnings.find({ address: findByAddress }), false); 
}

Comment: @Urigo I tried what you had and got `TypeError: The first argument of $meteorCollection must be a function or a have a find function property.`

Answer (score 0):

From angular-meteor [docs](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/meteorObject), it appears that `$meteor.object` will soon be deprecated.

There is no need for `$meteor.object` anymore as we can use Mongo Collection’s `findOne` function, like so.

**Old code:**

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId);
```

**New Code:**

```
$scope.helpers({
  party() {
    return Parties.findOne($stateParams.partyId);
  }
});
```

More detailed [bind one tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bind-one-object).